# What is creating these br-##### bridges?

Tags: networkmanager, bridge

What is creating these bridges (as visible in the NetworkManager) upon start?

I have to delete them all every time in order for internet connectivity on a certain WiFi point to work, and as far as I see there are no adverse effects to removing them.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: br-#### bridges in NetworkManager overview]

Comment: Maybe snapd ? ...

Comment: Quite possibly... and I haven't tried networking from a snap program, so I could be breaking it for them.

Comment: `docker` is creating these bridges. I have the same issue and the same workaround:-(

Answer (score 0):

These bridges are being created by `docker-compose`. They run in a 172.x.x.x address space by default.

This can lead to issues with other networks having the same address space.

To get around this issue, edit `docker-compose.yml` and insert the following:

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -  subnet: 10.1.100.0/24
```

You might need to replace this subnet with one that does not conflict with your usual networks.

Comment: Would you know how to find out which docker-compose? I have no active containers running.